# "Обежать вокруг", "Привееет", ложный деепричастный оборот

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

> Я сидела с идиотской улыбкой и играла с ними <детёнышами белух>, даже
>   не знаю сколько времени, пока не опомнилась: зачем вообще сюда пришла?
>   Вскочила, **обежала вокруг бассейна** и кричу: «Это надо снимать!
>   Немедленно. Я сейчас вернусь!» Бегу я теперь уже мимо афалин и
>   огромной белухи: «Эй! **Привееет**, ребята! Сейчас!» Дверь на себя,
>   кубарем по лестнице за Димкой и… натыкаюсь я внизу, на лестничной
>   площадке, на страшное его лицо и понимаю: случилось что-то
>   непоправимое.

*Я сидела с идиотской улыбкой и играла с ними <детёнышами белух> даже не знаю сколько времени, пока не опомнилась...* - "даже" отменяет запятую перед?

*Привееет, ребята!* - обязательно ли рисовать дефисы: приве-э-эт"? ***Е***-то у нас конвертируется в ***э***, безобразие получается...

Никто не ставит точку после закрывающих кавычек с предшествующим знаком: неэстетично, грязно, режет глаз... Однако правило диктует, при несовпадении интонации, - как выкручиваетесь вы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) ***Даже не знаю сколько времени*** ―  это устойчивый оборот со значением "очень долго", запятая не нужна, частица ДАЖЕ относится к обороту.

2) Все пишут *прив-е-ет!  http://translatedlyrics.ru/twenty_one_pilots/trees.html

3) Кажется, можно использовать **тире**.

Вскочила, обежала вокруг бассейна и кричу: «Это надо снимать! Немедленно. Я сейчас вернусь!» ― Бегу я теперь уже мимо афалин и огромной белухи: «Эй! Приве-е-ет, ребята! Сейчас!» ―  Дверь на себя, кубарем по лестнице за Димкой и…